# How do I make the transform style be smooth when toggling flat to skewed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a button that when pressed, toggles one class to another. I want the element to appear 2D flat by default and then skewed when the button is pressed. This is working how I want to but now I am trying to get it to be a smooth transition.
When I use the 'transition-duration' property it seems to appear so much larger and then return to the other state. I would like it to go from one state to the other but smoothly without it coming forward so much.
This is the example I have: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxthmps2/)

```js
 var trigger = 1;
function skewFix() 
{
if(trigger == 0)
  {
document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.add('box2');
document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.remove('box');
document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.toggle('box');
trigger = 1;
  }
  else if(trigger == 1){
  
document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.add('box');
document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.remove('box2');
  trigger = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.box { 
background-color: black;
color: white; width:100px; 
height: 100px;
margin: 30px;
-webkit-transform:  perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg) ;
transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.box2 { 
background-color: black;
color: white;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 30px;
-webkit-transform:  perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg);
transition-duration: 500ms;
}
}

.box2 { background-color: black; color: white; width:100px; height: 100px;margin: 30px;

-webkit-transform:  perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg);
transition-duration: 500ms;

}
```

```html
<div id="heyBox" class='box2'>hey</div>

<button type="button" onclick="skewFix()">Click Me!</button>
```

I have tried with the 'transition-duration' property but it seems to have this bouncing effect going on which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I’m not exactly clear what effect you want. It looks as though it’s a rotation about the bottom of the rectangle but you are changing perspective, ie as if the viewer is moving. Could you describe what is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the place the viewer is standing is being altered.

This snippet keeps the viewer stationery (perspective remains the same) and rotates the object about its bottom (using transform-origin).

```js
var trigger = 1;

function skewFix() {
  if (trigger == 0) {
    document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.add('box2');
    document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.remove('box');
    document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.toggle('box');
    trigger = 1;
  } else if (trigger == 1) {

    document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.add('box');
    document.getElementById("heyBox").classList.remove('box2');
    trigger = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg);
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(0deg);
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="heyBox" class='box2'>hey</div>

<button type="button" onclick="skewFix()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of setting the box2 transform to inherit.

```
.box2 { 
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 30px;
    -webkit-transform:  inherit;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    }
```

Comment: this is not what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/eom86L0q/
You need to prevent the expanding and smooth transition right? Please check in the fiddle and let us know if you are looking for something else.